# Update chart title when drilling up and down in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I'd like to update the chart title when drilling up and down. I managed to do it when drilling down, but can't figure a way to do it when drilling up.

Try my jsfiddle and see what i'm about: http://jsfiddle.net/By3s2/1/

```
chart: {
                type: 'column',
                events:{
                    drilldown: function(e){
                        var chart = this;
                        chart.setTitle({text: e.point.name});

                    },
                    drillup: function(e){
                       //?
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: Do you ever have to do multiple levels of drilldown? Otherwise you could just store the original title in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only using a single level of drilldown you could use a variable to hold the top level title and you would know that any time you are drilling up, you are going to the top level and should display that title instead. If you have multiple levels of drilldown you will have to figure out which level you are at, and the appropriate title. Checking against `event.seriesOptions` for `drillup` can assist in solving this.

Variables:

```
var chart;
var topLevelSeriesName = "Brands";
var topLevelTitle = "Browser market shares. November, 2013";
var topLevelSubtitle = "Click the columns to view versions. Source: netmarketshare.com.";
```

Chart settings:

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        renderTo: 'container',
        title: {
            text: topLevelTitle
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: topLevelSubtitle
        },
        events:{
            drilldown: function(e){
                var chart = this;
                chart.setTitle({text: e.point.name}, {text: ''});

            },
            drillup: function(e){
                if(e.seriesOptions.name == topLevelSeriesName) {
                    chart.setTitle({text: topLevelTitle}, {text: topLevelSubtitle});
                }
                else {
                    chart.setTitle({text: e.seriesOptions.name}, {text: ''});
                }
            }
        }
    },

    ...

    series: [{
        name: topLevelSeriesName,
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: brandsData
    }]

    ...

});
```

This should cover multiple levels of drilldown and changing of titles. See [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/By3s2/2/).